# REGEX in NP++: How to find the first } and delete it in a file

Tags: notepad++, regex

These are the starting lines in one of many files:

```
393
394
395.1.17 = { 123 134 121 1211 }
395.1.18 = { 132 1334 12121 1211211 }
395.1.19 = { 132 1334 12121 1211211 }
```

I'd like to remove the first } occurring (and only the first) so that it looks like this:

```
393
394
395.1.17 = { 123 134 121 1211
395.1.18 = { 132 1334 12121 1211211 }
395.1.19 = { 132 1334 12121 1211211 }
```

How could I do that through regular expressions in Notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

This does the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^([^}]+)\}(.*)$`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of string
  (         : start group 1
    [^}]+   : 1 or more any character that is NOT }
  )         : end group 1
  \}        : a close bracket
  (         : start group 2
    .*      : 0 or more any character
  )         : end group 2
$           : end of string
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1  : content of group 1 (ie. Everything that is before the first })
$2  : content of group 2 (ie. Everything that is after the first })
```

**Result for given example:**

```
393
394
395.1.17 = { 123 134 121 1211 
395.1.18 = { 132 1334 12121 1211211 }
395.1.19 = { 132 1334 12121 1211211 }
```

Comment: Your thank is nice but you forgot accepting this answer (click on the check mark) - 2 reputation for you and 15 for @Andréas . Moreover, you may upvote it (click on the triangular up arrow).

Comment: @Andréas: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers